# How to make UITabbar transparent so that background image of superview is visible?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar

I've used **UITabbar**. I've set it's background color to clear color. Even though the black colored background is appearing. I debugged the view and found that the UITabbar has implemented **UIVisualEffectSubView** and **UIVisualEffectBackdropView** to black color implicitly. What could be the better way to make it transparent with swift 4. Image of debug is attached below. 
[image]

Comment: you have tried `tintColor` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
yourTabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // clears the background
yourTabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
yourTabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()  // removes the border
```

**iOS 15 UPDATE**

For Coloured background

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .YourColor
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

For Transparent Appearance

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the barTintColor on your tabBar

```
tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```